# Подскажите, как поправить код, чтобы менялся цвет при наведении у все h1?

Tags: javascript, css

Подскажите, как поправить код. Сейчас, если стоит querySelector, то скрипт работает, но только с одним h1, а если менять допустим на getElementsByTagName(), то скрипт вообще перестает работать.

```js
var h = document.querySelector('h1');
var p = h.getBoundingClientRect();
var c = document.querySelector('.cursor');

document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {
  /*Adjust the position of the cursor*/
  c.style.left = e.clientX - 50 + 'px';
  c.style.top = e.clientY - 50 + 'px';
  /*Adjust the radial-gradient*/
  h.style.setProperty('--x', (e.clientX - p.top) + 'px');
  h.style.setProperty('--y', (e.clientY - p.left) + 'px');
}
```

```css
h1 {
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

h1:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-text);
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  clip-path: circle(50px at var(--x, -100px) var(--y, -100px));
}

.cursor {
  position: fixed;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: calc(calc(var(--y) * 1px) - 50px);
  left: calc(calc(var(--x) * 1px) - 50px);
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-text="WORK1">WORK1</h1>
<h1 data-text="WORK2">WORK2</h1>
<h1 data-text="WORK">WORK</h1>




<span class="cursor"></span>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/liza_cheptsova/pen/BaaLmvg)

Comment: потому что вы выбрали только 1 `h1` тег, а не все

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уверен, можно придумать куда лучше как это сделать, но меня хватило только на это.

Ну и тут все зависит от паддингов и размеров, так как если что-нибудь поменяется, нужно будет вручную всё менять.

```js
var cursor = document.querySelector('span');

document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', moveCursor);

function moveCursor({
  clientX,
  clientY
}) {
  cursor.style.left = `${clientX - 50}px`;
  cursor.style.top = `${clientY - 50}px`;

  setProperties(clientX, clientY);
}

function setProperties(clientX, clientY) {
  var elemBelow = document.elementFromPoint(clientX, clientY);

  if (elemBelow.tagName === 'H1') {
    var {
      left,
      top
    } = elemBelow.getBoundingClientRect();

    elemBelow.style.setProperty('--x', `${clientX - left - 50}px`);
    elemBelow.style.setProperty('--y', `${clientY - top - 50}px`);
    elemBelow.addEventListener('mouseleave', setDefaultProperties);
  }
}

function setDefaultProperties({
  target
}) {
  target.style.setProperty('--x', '-100px');
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

h1::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  clip-path: circle(50px at var(--x, -100px) var(--y, -100px));
}

span {
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(calc(var(--y) * 1px) - 50px);
  left: calc(calc(var(--x) * 1px) - 50px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-text="WORK1">WORK1</h1>
<h1 data-text="WORK2">WORK2</h1>
<h1 data-text="WORK3">WORK3</h1>
<span></span>
```